# Can't connect Kobo Libre

Tags: usb

Tried 3 USB3 ports, 2 USB-C ports

I get "Connect" dialog in Kobo

output from sudo dmesg -c

```
> [46831.897722] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd 
> [46832.049784] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2237,  idProduct=4234, bcdDevice= 4.01 
> [46832.049795] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5 
> [46832.049799] usb 2-1: Product: eReader-4.37.21586 
> [46832.049803] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Kobo
> [46832.049805] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: N4181A1009003 
> [46832.063110] BPF:    type_id=1810 bits_offset=2432 
> [46832.063113] BPF:  
> [46832.063114] BPF: Invalid name 
> [46832.063115] BPF:  
> [46832.063116] failed to validate module [usb_storage] BTF: -22 
> [46832.135822] BPF: type_id=1810 bits_offset=2432 
> [46832.135826] BPF:   
> [46832.135827] BPF: Invalid name 
> [46832.135828] BPF:  
> [46832.135829] failed to validate module [usb_storage] BTF: -22
```

Please help, I'm very stupid

P.S. Resetting Kobo in not an option, too much at stake